# Show data from datagridview to reportviewer C#

Tags: c#, excel, pdf, datagridview, reportviewer

I have a datagridview and I would like to pass data to reportviewer, so in this way I can print and export to pdf/excel easily.
How can I do it please? or is there another solution to get my goal? Thank you! :)

Comment: Which type of `DataSource` do you use for your `DataGridView`?

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to pass GridView data to ReportViewer, the first thing you got to do is retrieve the datasource of gridview as shown below:

```
BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)GridView1.DataSource;//You should first convert DataSourse into Binding Sourse
DataTable dt = (DataTable) bs.DataSource; //Get GridView data source to Data table
```

Now You got your GridView data in **DataTable dt**, you can bind ReportViewer to DataTable as shown below:

```
ReportViewer ReportViewer1 = new ReportViewer(); //Your ReportViewer Control
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1_Customers_DataTable1",dt); // ReportViewerDataSource : ReportViewer is to be bind to this DataSource
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear(); // Clear the Previous DataSource of ReportViewer
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds); //bind ReportViewer1 to the new datasource(Which you wish)
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh(); // Refresh the ReportViewer Control, ReportViewer1 in this case
```

thats all, you're done!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am a newbie about C# and Visual Studio in general. I have some questions about your code: 1) I need to have datagridview and reportviewer in the same form?
2) In whitch event I need to put them? in a button? form load? I know those questions are stupid, but I am learning now :)
Thanks!

Comment: No need to have datagridview and reportviewer in the same form. You can pass data between Gridview on one form to ReportViewer on another form, you may google for 'Passing data between windows forms in C#' to get an idea. But since you are a newbie I would recommend using datagridview and reportviewer in the same form. Once you get to know how  to pass data from GridView to reportviewer, you may try to achieve the same with both controls not on same form.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Ans-2: Try adding a button next to your Gridview (button Text: 'Generate Report') and on the click event of this button put the code for binding reportviewer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got error: I put datagridview and reportviewer in the same form; I put first code into form_load; I put second code into a button. When I run my project, I got this error:
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataSet' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource'"
What Can I do, please? :)

Comment: make the following correction in first code:

     var bs = (BindingSource)GridView1.DataSource;
     var dt = (DataTable) bs.DataSource;

This will eliminate the error

Comment: But make sure you declare "var dt" as a global variable so that it will be available for Form_Load and Button_Click functions".