# Report Viewer for filtered data of Datagridview VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, reportviewer

I filtered data using bindingsource filter and displayed it in datagridview
 and i want to print the data of datagridview in reportviewer 
please help me

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow! It helps to get your question answered if you include an mcve http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve along with what you've tried and the error(s) you're getting.

Comment: Also, this other question may or may not be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314032/show-data-from-datagridview-to-reportviewer-c-sharp